# 'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UINavigationController'?

Tags: uiview, xcode4.3, uisplitviewcontroller, uianimation

I just compile my ipad apps in portrait view, I just move to **my view to split view** and back to the view I faced the error:

> Unbalanced calls to **begin/end appearance transitions** for
>   **UINavigationController**

I am working in xcode 4.3.2. I just compiled the xcode 4.2 version it has no issues. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 4.2.1 i am adding this codes

```
if (popoverController != nil){[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];}
```

In xcode 4.3 no need above code.That was the issue i faced.
Thank you...